# Jenkins: Environment variables not available in CMake

Tags: bash, cmake, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins job running on Kubuntu 14.04.3 consists out of two build steps:

1. Setting environment variables in bash via "Execute shell"
2. Executing a "CMake Build" process

My CMake scripts are very system dependent, which means that I exhaustively use the `$ENV{UNIX_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}` command.

But the problem is, that the variables which I have set in the first step, can not be seen by CMake in the second one.
I've tried different solution:

1. Setting the variables via "Execute shell" build step via "export VAR=VAL"
2. Setting the variables via "export VAR=VAL" in the .bashrc of the jenkins user

I use for all configuration steps and as the common shell in Jenkins "/bin/bash".

It defenetly works with the "EnvInject" plugin, and if I add the variables to the "/etc/environment" file.
So my question is, what is wrong with the first two solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables are per-process (and child processes).

So assuming "Execute Shell" runs its own shell then those variables won't be visible for any other spawned processes.

The `.bashrc` of the jenkins use should work **assuming** the spawned shell is an interactive shell (which is almost certainly isn't).

Try `.bash_login` for that instead.

That being said it would seem that whatever `EnvInject` is likely the better idea.